# injecting a service by interface

Tags: loopback4

I like to code to interfaces.  So... I have an interface.. 'MyService' and an class 'MyServiceImpl implements MyService'.   I have a controller with constructor:

```
constructor(@service() private myService : MyService){}
```

or

```
constructor(@service('services.MyService') private myService : MyService){}
```

And... this doesn't work.  I'm missing a binding.. or something.  I can decorate MyServiceImpl with @injectable, but loopback can't seem to recognize that 'MyServiceImpl' is a 'MyService.  I tried creating a 'MyServiceProvider',

```
injectable.provider({scope: BindingScope.SINGLETON})
export class MyServiceProvider implements Provider<MyService> {...}
```

but no joy.  I'm even seeing:

```
loopback:context:binding Bind services.MyService to provider MyServiceProvider.
```

But.. no matter what I try, I still get

```
 Error: No binding found for services.MyService
Make sure a service binding is created in context MyAppApplication-Sowav28XQmuFEB31ZTvPMQ-0 with serviceInterface (services.MyService)
```

Answer (score 0):

@service never worked for me, but @inject worked fine... though not by interface, but by key... which is sufficient for me for now.